# Raspbian autostarting a PyQT5 UI that has Serial communication

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyqt5, raspbian

I'd designed a python software that required to start right after boot into system. I'd use `sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to add in `@python3 /home/pi/X/exe.py`

Before I'd include serial communication into the apps, everything works fine.

But after I'd add in serial, the autostart had failed.

So, how to autostart on boot a PyQt5 based serial comn.-able apps in Raspbian Jessie?

I'd been suspecting that this weird behavior is due to serial communication that I'd added, that will be used before Pi logon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd decided to reflash the image and my problem is solved.